# Java Swing progress bar for download process

Tags: java, swing, backend, frontend, jprogressbar

I am using Java function to download file from internet.

```
public void getLatestRelease()
{
    try
    {
        // Function called
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Open connection
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        URL url = new URL(latestReleaseUrl);
        url.openConnection();

        // Download routine
        InputStream reader = url.openStream();
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("release.zip");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[153600];
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            buffer = new byte[153600];
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        }

        // Download finished
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Output download information
        System.out.println("Done.");
        System.out.println((new Integer(totalBytesRead).toString()) + " bytes read.");
        System.out.println("It took " + (new Long(endTime - startTime).toString()) + " milliseconds.");

        // Close input and output streams
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    // Here I catch MalformedURLException and IOException :)
}
```

And I have `JProgressBar` component in my `JPanel`, which is supposed to visualize download progress:

```
private static void createProgressBar(JPanel panel)
{
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

I'd like to separate "back-end" functions from "front-end" views, presented to users, by analogy with MVC in web applications.

So, function `getLatestRelease()` lies in the package `framework` in class `MyFramework`.

Everything, connected with `Swing` interface generation, including event listeners, is in the package `frontend`.

In the main `Controller` class I create an instance of `MyFramework` and an instance of `ApplicationFrontend`, which is the main class of `frontend` package.

The questions is how to update `progressBar` value, depending on download progress?

Comment: You would do this by using listeners such as a PropertyChangeListener added to the SwingWorker that is doing the downloading.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, I'll google for it.

Comment: consider using a [ProgressMonitorInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) to assist you in this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you want to do MVC in swing, the `SwingWorker` class comes to mind.
SwingWorker comes with a property called "progress", that you can listen to using a `PropertyChangeListener`.

Progress events can be fired from the swingworker using its `setProgress(int 0-100)` method. So here it is for loading the file in the background with a notion of progress (note that you will need to have an idea of the size of the file to be able to compute a progress percentage).

Showing the progress can be done using two options : a `JProgressBar` for complete control, or a `ProgressMonitor` to show an almost self-managed popup with a progress bar in it. See the  [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#deciding) to see the differences.

### Solution 1

As they say, if you go for a `ProgressMonitor` and your background task is reading from an `InputStream`, you can use the [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) class to do the reading and displaying progress without bothering with calling setProgress or listening to the "progress" property.

### Solution 2

If you want to do it manually, create your SwingWorker loading task that calls setProgress as it goes, instanciate a ProgressMonitor (or a JProgressBar) as needed, register a PropertyChangeListener on your SwingWorker that checks for "progress" changes and updates the monitor/bar accordingly.

**Note:** It is important to go through a PropertyChangeListener because it decouples the model (the task) from the view (the swing progress component) and abide by the EDT usage rules.

Comment: note that in solution 1 you should still use a SwingWorker, only it will instanciate a ProgressMonitorInputStream instead of calling setProgress...